# Which country of Africa has the highest number of Esperanto-speakers?

Tags: movado, esperanto-speakers

Africa is known for not having a lot of Esperanto-speakers. Still, which country does a good job at it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Measuring numbers of Esperanto speakers is notoriously difficult, but UEA does publish some enlightening figures about its member countries, including [African ones](http://www.uea.org/landoj/afriko).

Judging by UEA members, the most active country is [**Togo**](http://www.uea.org/landoj/togolando), with **28 UEA members**.

Judging by members of the national organisation, [**Benin**](http://www.uea.org/landoj/benino) is on top, reporting **500 members of the national Esperanto organisation.**

How exactly this translates into Esperanto speakers is difficult, but in general the UEA figures give at least a good relative perspective on Esperanto in Africa.

Answer (score 1):

As some numbers have already been provided and as was mentioned, official numbers are quite difficult to calculate, I'm going to first mention some personal experience. Most African Esperanto speakers I have chatted with online have been from the Democratic Republic of the Congo, Togo, Burundi, and Benin. I have recently met one person from Nigeria.

There is also the recently-launched [Aminda Radio Esperanto](https://djpod.com/amindaesperanto), out of Madagascar.

On [edukado.net](http://edukado.net/prie/sinprezento/statistiko?tipo=uzantoj), Congo-Kinshasa (Democratic Republic of the Congo) is the first African country I see, with 18 users listed as being from there. Next is Togo with 14, next are Senegal, Burundi, and Algeria--you'll find more countries listed as well as the numbers of users on the linked page.

Lernu also keeps statistics of its users' country of origin. I am pressed for time now as I write this and will try to find that info soon.

Edit: I am having trouble finding a page of Lernu's stats all laid out in one spot since Lernu's site redesign, but [here](http://lernu.net/en/uzantoj) is where you can search users by country, language(s), and gender. You'd have to go through each African country to see the numbers this way. I contacted the Lernu team to see if they can link me to a statistics page, if one still exists, but at least this way you can still gain some idea.